# Nextjs: Render data from GET request each time the page loads

Tags: reactjs, static, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to load data from a GET request into a table on my Next.js site. It works fine when I run it locally but when I publish it to a static site, it does not update the table each time.

I figured out that it pulls the data into a static HTML page when you export it to a static site but I want it to pull the data into the table each time. How do I ensure that it only populates the data with the data from the GET request and not the one on the static HTML page?

I am using the following code to perform the get request:

```
static getInitialProps = async function() {

    var data;
    await axios.get('https://myapi.com')
        .then(res => {
            data = res.data;
        });
    return {
        items: data.TableData
    }

}
```

I expect it to pull the data each time but it only pulls it on when I export it and it doesn't change thereafter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the data at runtime, you can use the `componentDidMount` life cycle hook and put it in the component state instead.

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const res = await axios.get('https://myapi.com')
  this.setState({ items: res.data });
}
```

Comment: Also, be sure to ensure that you are in the client side by wrapping it in a conditional, i.e. `if (typeof window != 'undefined')`

Comment: @cr05s19xx `componentDidMount` is not called on the server, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Alright. But at a point, I had an instance where it was rendered and threw an error, so I usually use it in cases where I will need a client side object, like `localstorage`

Comment: @cr05s19xx Yeah, it's good practice to check for `window` like you mentioned if you use a browser-specific API in e.g. the constructor of the component.

Comment: Thank you for assuring me @Tholle. I thought I was breaking it somewhere 

Comment: I have wrapped the GET request in the useEffect() hook but it is still not populating the data from get request in production (works on the localhost though). I checked from the network tab, the request was in wait for about a minute or around 45 seconds; then it threw 504 gateway timeout. Any suggestions? 

(between, there are other GET requests in that same useEffect but those are working fine. This request fetches JSON that is not working on the production server)